React Native: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView - Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Description
I am trying to create iOS Intent Extension on a React Native project. The requirement is to render the UI on React Native. I have followed the step here https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps?language=swift but encountering an issue when building my project where the linker command fails with the following error message:
Showing All Issues
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTRootView
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
React Native Version
0.74.1, & 0.72.4,
Platform
iOS
Reproducer
https://github.com/AhmadQuraishi/RNExtensionIssue.git
